# Graph orientation and node positioning in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, graph, d3.js, force-layout

Thanks to this earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11894057/1036544), I produced a static fixed-layout graph as below using force layout in `d3.js`:

[image]

and I have two specific questions to further customize the layout:

First, I notice that initializing nodes positions deterministically (e.g. done diagonally here, see the [script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11894057/1036544) for details) fixes the positions of the nodes, and the orientation of the nodes seem to depend on this initialization as well as the dimensions of the force graph*. I wonder how can I make the nodes `A, D, E, F, I` in the graph above **aligned horizontally**? In other words, I want to turn the orientation of the graph anti-clockwise for roughly 45 degrees. I have tried to initialize the nodes horizontally in the middle:

```
nodes.forEach(function(d, i) { d.x = w / size * i; d.y = h / 2; });
```

but the produced output has all the nodes and edges horizontally at where they were initialized.

Second, is it true that the force graph is automatically centered within the `svg` element? If no, how can we make it so? If yes, how can we specify a center for the force graph within the `svg` element?

(* Note: strangely, when setting `.size([w, h])` where `w = h` for the force graph, and deterministically initializing the nodes along a diagonal, all the nodes and edges are positioned along that diagonal in the output, why?)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a custom gravity force applied on each tick which pulls the nodes towards the horizontal line. Something like this:

```
force.on('tick', function(e) {
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y += (height/2 - d.y) * e.alpha;
  });
})
```

To your second question, I believe, it is not centered, but there is a small gravity force by default which pulls the nodes towards the center.