# Network multi-route orthogonal graph in d3.js

Tags: graph, svg, d3.js, javascript

We want to use d3 to draw a network route graph that has fixed start and end node but different paths in between that might share some nodes, for example:
[image]

I read comments from [Configure fixed-layout static graph in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894057/configure-fixed-layout-static-graph-in-d3-js) and successfully created a simple graph like:

[image]

But as I add more nodes to the graph it becomes random (not static after refresh) and not orthogonal anymore:

[image]

**So my questions are:**

- Is it possible to use d3.js to draw something close to the desired
  graph?
- Or is there an algorithm out there I should employ in my
  graph implementation?

Comment: It looks like you're initializing the force when you add new nodes. Is this using the force-directed layout? If so, then you need to remove any reference to force.start() or force.restart() to keep it from returning to a force-directed state.

Comment: Yes: I am using force-directed layout. Did you mean to remove force-directed layout? How could I make sure the nodes do not collide without a repulsion force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dagre](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre) solved our problem. It does exactly what we need.

Answer (score 3):

See my demo here。

http://jsfiddle.net/doraeimo/JEcdS/

The main idea is to make a connectivity based on a tree.

```
    //1)temporarily convert a connectivity to a tree        
    var tree = conv2tree(data);

    //2)calculate for nodes' coords with <code>cluster.nodes(tree);</code>
    var nodes = buildNodes(tree);

    //3)append all the edges(links) of the connectivity
    var links = buildLinks(data);
```

Comment: The nodes systemD/E/F/G stack together though. Dagre solved our problem - it aligns the nodes very nicely.

Comment: Nice! I think it's hard to do align for any complex network graph automatically. Is there some special algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

I built an example using Dagre-d3, which integrates Dagre (suggested by @frank) with D3.

```js
// Display options
var options = {
  rankdir: "LR"
};

// Create the input graph
var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph()
  .setGraph(options)
  .setDefaultEdgeLabel(function() {
    return {};
  });

// Set nodes
var n_nodes = 8;
for (var i = 0; i < n_nodes; i++) {
  g.setNode(i, {
    label: i
  });
}

g.nodes().forEach(function(v) {
  var node = g.node(v);
  node.shape = "circle";
});

// Set edges
g.setEdge(0, 1);
g.setEdge(1, 2);
g.setEdge(2, 3);
g.setEdge(3, 4);
g.setEdge(4, 5);
g.setEdge(1, 1);
g.setEdge(1, 6);
g.setEdge(6, 7);
g.setEdge(7, 0);
g.setEdge(7, 4);

// Create the renderer
var render = new dagreD3.render();

// Set up an SVG group so that we can translate the final graph.
var svg = d3.select("svg");

// Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
render(svg, g);
```

```css
.node {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.node circle {
  stroke: darkgray;
  fill: lightgray;
}

.edgePath path {
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dagre-d3/0.6.1/dagre-d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width=960 height=600></svg>
```