# D3 - Create directed graph left-to-right layout and orthogonal edges/connectors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use D3 to create a create a maintainable and customizable map of my application, which has 100+ screens on it in different sections, a bit like a flow chart but much simpler, like the following example:

[image]

I believe this would be called a "directed graph", and I have checked out lots of projects that use `d3.layout.force` to generate the layouts, but is there a type of layout that would allow me to keep the flow from left to right and the lines generally running at right angles to each other, as well as corner radii for the line?

I just am very new to D3 and feel I just may not be searching for the right graph name or missing a library that would be useful for this purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network multi-route orthogonal graph in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424533/network-multi-route-orthogonal-graph-in-d3-js)